# $\sum\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}$ converges if and only if $\sum\frac{a_n}{S_n}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_n>0$ and
$$S_0=1,S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k.$$
We have the result [$\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum\frac{a_n}{S_n}$ conveges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820651/sum-n-geq-0a-n-converges-iff-sum-n-geq-0-fraca-n-sum-k-0n-a-k).
And also we can show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\ \mbox{converges}\iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}\ \mbox{converges}.$$

$\textbf{Proof:}$ If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $S_n\to S>0$, and
$$\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}\sim\frac{a_n}{S},\ \ n\to\infty.$$
So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}$ converges.

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges, then $S_n\to \infty$, and
$$\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}>\log\left(1+\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}\right)
=\log S_n-\log S_{n-1},$$
this implies
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{S_{k-1}}>\log S_{n+1}\to\infty, n\to\infty.$$
So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}$ diverges.

Combining the above two result, we can conclude that
$$\color{red}{\sum\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}\ \mbox{converges}\iff \sum\frac{a_n}{S_n}\ \mbox{converges}}.$$

$\textbf{My question is that is there a direct method to prove:}$
$$\color{red}{\sum\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}\ \mbox{converges}\iff \sum\frac{a_n}{S_n}\ \mbox{converges}}.$$
One direction is very easy due to
$$\frac{a_n}{S_n}<\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}.$$

> It is expected to give a direct proof of
> $$\sum\frac{a_n}{S_n}\ \mbox{converges}\implies \sum\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}\ \mbox{converges}$$

Any help and hints will welcome.

> > Is the following generalization is right?
> > For fixed positive integer $k$,
> > $$\color{red}{\sum_{n\geq k}\frac{a_n}{S_{n-k}}\ \mbox{converges}\iff \sum\frac{a_n}{S_n}\ \mbox{converges}}.$$

Comment: It does not affect your statement, but I would consider $S_0 = 0$ a more natural choice, instead of $S_0 = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noticed, the implication
$$
\sum_{n> k}\frac{a_n}{S_{n-k}}\ \mbox{converges}\implies \sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{a_n}{S_n}\ \mbox{converges}
$$
follows immediately from the estimate $\frac{a_n}{S_n} \le \frac{a_n}{S_{n-k}}$.

For the other direction we can mimic the proof in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/820670/42969) that you referred to. If $\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{a_n}{S_n}$ converges then there is an index $N$ such that for $q > p \ge N$
$$
 \frac 12 \ge \sum_{n=p+1}^q \frac{a_n}{S_n} \ge \sum_{n=p+1}^q \frac{a_n}{S_q}
= \frac{S_q-S_p}{S_q} = 1 - \frac{S_p}{S_q}
$$
and therefore $ S_q \le 2 S_p$. It follows that
$$
 \frac{a_n}{S_{n-k}} \le 2  \frac{a_n}{S_{n}}
$$
for $n \ge N+k$, so that $\sum_{n> k}\frac{a_n}{S_{n-k}}$ converges.

This proves the conjectured generalisation. It is a “direct” proof in the sense that we did not work with the convergence or divergence of $\sum a_n$.

Comment: Nice answer!  Thank you very much.